# In Postgres how to join tables with columns of the same name, and alter column name?

Tags: postgresql

I have two tables, `A` and `B` with a variety of columns, some of which are the same name.

```
CREATE TABLE A (
    id serial PRIMARY KEY,
    col_a int,
    col_b int,
    col_c int
);

CREATE TABLE A (
    id serial PRIMARY KEY,
    col_a int,
    col_b int,
    col_e int
);
```

I want to join the two tables on `col_a`, like following:

```
select * from A a join B b USING(col_a)
```

Ultimately, I want to create a view from this query `create view my_view as (...)`. But when I do, I get an error because the columns `id` and `col_b` appear twice. Is there a way to, on the join, prepend/append a prefix/suffix to the columns of table `B`, so there are no name clashes?

### **Edit**

Just to clarify, I do NOT want to use aliases because in practise my tables have O(50) columns and I want to use the wildcard operator `*`. This is definitely a solved problem if you use aliases, but particularly in my case where I am creating views of views of views, I want syntactic sugar to make it simpler.

Comment: use an alias? `select a.id as a_great_new_name`

Comment: Ah sorry I should have clarified that I don't want to go the alias route. Will update the question.

Comment: select * from A a join B b on a.col_a = b.col_a;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [composite values](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rowtypes.html) in your views, i.e. defining the view as having two columns, one with the `A` value and one with the `B` value:

```
CREATE VIEW my_view AS SELECT a, b from A a join B b USING (col_a);
```

They are a bit ugly to [use in queries](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rowtypes.html#ROWTYPES-USAGE) though, always requiring parenthesis to disambiguate the [field selection expressions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#FIELD-SELECTION):

```
SELECT (v.a).col_a, (v.a).id AS a_id, (v.b).id AS b_id FROM my_view v;
SELECT (a).col_a, (a).id AS a_id, (b).id AS b_id FROM my_view;
```

<sup>([online demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/lUTzIGdH))</sup>

This is the closest you will get to a "prefix" though that can be automatically generated in the view definition. As soon as you define views of views, you should still (explicitly) name the underlying tables though not nest composite types further.

Comment: Thanks @Bergi. This is definitely the closest to what I was looking for, and I certainly learned something new anyway.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to prepend/append a prefix/suffix to the columns of table B, so there are no name clashes, without enumerating the columns and using alias column names for the result set?

**No.** Sad but true.

Answer (score 0):

You can match and join columns that have similar names using `NATURAL JOIN`, try running the query

```
CREATE VIEW my_view AS
SELECT *
FROM A NATURAL JOIN B;
```

Comment: Isn't that what `USING(col_a)` as the join condition already does?

Comment: Thanks @Nnaemeka, but the issue here is that in my case I don't want to join on `col_b`, and `NATURAL JOIN` would end up trying to join on `A.col_b=B.col_b`.

Answer (score -2):

you can use this

```
CREATE VIEW my_view AS
SELECT
a.*,
b.* AS b_
FROM
A a
JOIN
B b ON a.col_a = b.col_a;
```

In this example, I've used b.* AS b_ to effectively append an underscore to the columns from table B. This way, you can still use the wildcard operator * while avoiding column name conflicts.

Comment: [This does not appear to work](https://dbfiddle.uk/aSbe-97z)